# Unable to setup navdrawer to go over toolbar in the new 5.0 SDK using appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Has anyone successfully got the navigation drawer to open over top of a toolbar that is being used with setSupportActionBar(toolbar)?  I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

If I make the Toolbar a child of the Drawerlayout in my xml, then the toolbar fills the entire screen no matter what height I set it to.  The only other thing I could think of doing was wrapping my drawerlayout and toolbar in another parent layout and placing the toolbar outside of the navdrawer, but then the navdrawer opens up below the toolbar.

I was also not successful in getting the hamburger icon to transition to an arrow when using the navdrawer.  I am using the new ActionBarDrawerToggle from the v7 compat library as well.

So I created a new test project targetting api21 only and used the following XML, and it also has the same problem where the toolbar fills the entire screen.  The navdrawer DOES open over top of it in with this code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:name="com.example.testnav.NavigationDrawerFragment"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>

<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
         android:background="#43599a"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my toolbar code from my activity:

```
final DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    if (mActionBarToolbar != null) {
        setActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    }

    if (mActionBarToolbar != null) {
        mActionBarToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
        mActionBarToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a solution.

```
<!-- Main layout -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/headerbar"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--Toolbar-->   
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <include layout="@layout/main_container" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Nav drawer -->
<include layout="@layout/navdrawer" />
```

Another way is to put the toolbar inside the layout which you use in your main container.

Comment: This was the answer although I used a FrameLayout to wrap the main fragment layout and the toolbar.  Thanks